# Why are my ServiceStack.Razor pages not refreshing until I rebuild my app?

Tags: razor, servicestack, servicestack-bsd, servicestack-razor

I've got an API project hosted in ServiceStack (3.9), and I've added a /docs folder containing two Razor files, `_layout.cshtml` and `default.cshtml`

I have configured no caching; my AppHost class looks like this:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase {
    public AppHost() 
        : base("My API", typeof(UserService).Assembly, typeof(GetUserDto).Assembly) {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container) {
        ServiceExceptionHandler += 
            (req, request, exception) => {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
                return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
            };

        JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
        Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
        Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
    }

    public static void Start() {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

My Razor pages are working fine - going to localhost/api/docs shows the default page and uses the supplied layout - but if I make a change to the Razor code, I need to recompile the app before it's visible in a browser.

My understanding was that ServiceStack views worked like ASP.NET MVC views - they're interpreted at request time, and any changes to the view code show up immediately, and if you want to cache your rendered views you'll need to configure that explicitly. Have I missed a config setting, or is there something else I need to do to get ServiceStack pages to recompile without needing to rebuild the project?

Comment: Just spitballing. Do you have a `docs` folder in your project that contains your Razor pages, that has `Copy to Output Directory` on? Because this results in these files being copied to the `bin/debug/docs` folder on build which is where ServiceStack looks. So when you make a change, you are doing to in the source copy and not the build copy, so ServiceStack doesn't pick up on that, until you rebuild and the new copy is moved.

Comment: Nope - Copy to Output Directory is false on both the .cshtml files.

Comment: Did `DebugMode = true` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `AppHost` config to `debug` mode:

```cs
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    DebugMode = true,
});
```

For performance reasons changes are only monitored for in Debug mode. [See here](http://razor-console.servicestack.net/) for more information.

> **Automatic reload of modified views, layout templates and partials (in Debug mode)**
>
> The best way to avoid the Start-Up penalty is to avoid having to restart the AppDomain in the first place. So in Debug Mode we'll also do this where a background file system watcher monitors all pages, partials and Layout templates for modifications and recompiles and auto-reloads them on the fly, all-ready to deliever instant response time once the page is requested.